# My indicator triggers alarm even though it doesn't satisfy the alarm condition

Tags: pine-script

[My Indicator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3a2v.png)

I have an indicator that gives signals. The working logic is if the background is light red and the price touches the blue bar, give a short signal. As you can see in the picture, there is no signal because

```
plot(long_short==-1 ? shortStop : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.yellow, linewidth=3, title="Short Fixed SL")
plot(long_short==-1 ? shortTake : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.blue, linewidth=3, title="Short Fixed TP")
...
alertcondition(condition=short_last, title="Short Alarm", message='Open a Short Trade @ ${{close}}')
...
if(short_last)
    l = label.new(bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(l, "sell@\n"+str.tostring(close))
    label.set_color(l, color.red)
    label.set_yloc(l, yloc.abovebar)
    label.set_style(l, label.style_arrowdown)
```

If short_last was true, it should have tp/sl lines and the label like in the left signals, but it doesn't exist because short_last must be false. In other words, it should not have actually thrown a signal. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what caused the problem. When adding an alarm in Tradingview, it is added according to the default inputs of the indicator. I changed the inputs later, but since the alarms remained according to the default values, it actually appears as a light-red zone for another input, and that's why it triggered an alarm. Now I have to set 40 alarms again.